# GLIBC library version missmatch error while starting nodejs application on Openshift

Tags: linux, node.js, mongodb, openshift

I am newbie to MEAN stack and Linux hence please forgive me if my question is too obvious and stupid.

I have hosted a Nodejs application on Openshift. While trying to start the application I am facing following error due to GLIBC library version missmatch:

```
[Error: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /var/lib/openshift/550be20dfcf93378d600015e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/build/Release/bson.node)]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
/var/lib/openshift/550be20dfcf93378d600015e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').BSONPure.ObjectID;
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ObjectID' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550be20dfcf93378d600015e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/objectid.js:8:43)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550be20dfcf93378d600015e/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/lib/types/objectid.js:18:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Current version of GLIBC on Opneshift is 2.12.

One obvious solution which I know is to upgrade GLIBC on Openshift. However that is not feasible as I am not having sudo rights on openshift.

Is there any possible workaround to solve the same issue?

Comment: I meet the same issue with a PhantomJS binary I compiled on a Debian machine, have you found any solution yet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [js-bson error - Mosca (MQTT Broker) on OpenShift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623788/js-bson-error-mosca-mqtt-broker-on-openshift)