# js-bson error - Mosca (MQTT Broker) on OpenShift

Tags: node.js, openshift, bson

I've been doing some work with NodeJS on OpenShift and am facing a problem when I'm trying to run a Mosca server in a Node instance. The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
[Error: /var/lib/openshift/5547bd284382ec394a000088/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mosca/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build/Release/bson.node: invalid ELF header]
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I have recently created a new Application (on OpenShift) from scratch with a NodeJS cartridge and have cloned the sample app git repository from the cartridge as the starting point. Into this I have added mosca via npm (`npm install mosca --save`). Without even using Mongo as a persistent store for Mosca, so just running in memory, I get the error shown above when I run the application. It's fine when I run it on my laptop, same versions of everything, as far as I can tell.

I've already tried a few things I've found on Stack Overflow, such as building all the dependent modules before pushing code back to git and cleaning npm cache but to no avail.

I'd appreciate if anyone has had a similar experience with other modules or the same experience with Mosca and might be able to point me in the right direction.

Kind Regards.

The code below is the standard Node sample application template, with a sample Mosca server in the start function.

```
#!/bin/env node
//  OpenShift sample Node application
var express = require('express');
var fs      = require('fs');
var mosca   = require('mosca');

/**
 *  Define the sample application.
 */
var SampleApp = function() {

    //  Scope.
    var self = this;

    /*  ================================================================  */
    /*  Helper functions.                                                 */
    /*  ================================================================  */

    /**
     *  Set up server IP address and port # using env variables/defaults.
     */
    self.setupVariables = function() {
        //  Set the environment variables we need.
        self.ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
        self.port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

        if (typeof self.ipaddress === "undefined") {
            //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
            //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using 127.0.0.1');
            self.ipaddress = "127.0.0.1";
        };
    };


    /**
     *  Populate the cache.
     */
    self.populateCache = function() {
        if (typeof self.zcache === "undefined") {
            self.zcache = { 'index.html': '' };
        }

        //  Local cache for static content.
        self.zcache['index.html'] = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
    };


    /**
     *  Retrieve entry (content) from cache.
     *  @param {string} key  Key identifying content to retrieve from cache.
     */
    self.cache_get = function(key) { return self.zcache[key]; };


    /**
     *  terminator === the termination handler
     *  Terminate server on receipt of the specified signal.
     *  @param {string} sig  Signal to terminate on.
     */
    self.terminator = function(sig){
        if (typeof sig === "string") {
           console.log('%s: Received %s - terminating sample app ...',
                       Date(Date.now()), sig);
           process.exit(1);
        }
        console.log('%s: Node server stopped.', Date(Date.now()) );
    };


    /**
     *  Setup termination handlers (for exit and a list of signals).
     */
    self.setupTerminationHandlers = function(){
        //  Process on exit and signals.
        process.on('exit', function() { self.terminator(); });

        // Removed 'SIGPIPE' from the list - bugz 852598.
        ['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
         'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM'
        ].forEach(function(element, index, array) {
            process.on(element, function() { self.terminator(element); });
        });
    };


    /*  ================================================================  */
    /*  App server functions (main app logic here).                       */
    /*  ================================================================  */

    /**
     *  Create the routing table entries + handlers for the application.
     */
    self.createRoutes = function() {
        self.routes = { };

        self.routes['/asciimo'] = function(req, res) {
            var link = "http://i.imgur.com/kmbjB.png";
            res.send("<html><body><img src='" + link + "'></body></html>");
        };

        self.routes['/'] = function(req, res) {
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
            res.send(self.cache_get('index.html') );
        };
    };


    /**
     *  Initialize the server (express) and create the routes and register
     *  the handlers.
     */
    self.initializeServer = function() {
        self.createRoutes();
        self.app = express();

        //  Add handlers for the app (from the routes).
        for (var r in self.routes) {
            self.app.get(r, self.routes[r]);
        }
    };


    /**
     *  Initializes the sample application.
     */
    self.initialize = function() {
        self.setupVariables();
        self.populateCache();
        self.setupTerminationHandlers();

        // Create the express server and routes.
        self.initializeServer();
    };


    /**
     *  Start the server (starts up the sample application).
     */
    self.start = function() {
        //  Start the app on the specific interface (and port).
        self.app.listen(self.port, self.ipaddress, function() {
            console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                        Date(Date.now() ), self.ipaddress, self.port);
        });

        // START MOSCA SERVER

            var server = new mosca.Server({});

            server.on('clientConnected', function(client) {
                console.log('client connected', client.id);
            });

            // fired when a message is received
            server.on('published', function(packet, client) {
              console.log('Published', packet.payload);
            });

            server.on('ready', function() {
                console.log('Mosca server is up and running');
            });

    };

};   /*  Sample Application.  */



/**
 *  main():  Main code.
 */
var zapp = new SampleApp();
zapp.initialize();
zapp.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid ELF header usually means that the binary you are trying to execute was compiled on a system that is not compatible with the system you are trying to run it on (compiled on x86, running on x86_64, etc).  Are you committing your node_modules directory within your application to git?  You should let your OpenShift application install the correct node modules for you and not commit that directory / add it into your git version control system.

Comment: Thank you, that's actually got me to the right place. I hadn't noticed that the sample application structure includes a .gitkeep file in the node_modules, which means whatever I had built on my local system was being pushed to the OpenShift server at which point it fails. Changed it to a .gitignore (and removed the modules to force a rebuild) and it all works fine now. Thanks again.