# invalid ELF header with OpenShift Nodejs and node_modules/ursa

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am using OpenShift for uploading my first node js.

I am finding the following error in my log:

```
Error: /var/lib/openshift/558e94775973ca43a1000132/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/ursa/build/Release/ursaNative.node: invalid ELF header
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at bindings (/var/lib/openshift/558e94775973ca43a1000132/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/ursa/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/558e94775973ca43a1000132/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/ursa/lib/ursa.js:18:37)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at new crypto (/var/lib/openshift/558e94775973ca43a1000132/app-root/runtime/repo/utilities/crypto.js:3:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/558e94775973ca43a1000132/app-root/runtime/repo/utilities/crypto.js:22:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

can you please tell me what I should with **invalid ELF header** error.

Comment: Hi guys can you please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [js-bson error - Mosca (MQTT Broker) on OpenShift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623788/js-bson-error-mosca-mqtt-broker-on-openshift)